# How to create multiple PFUsers on Parse-Server?

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-server, pfuser

I am using the `PFUser` class to handle users (on Heroku/mLab) in an iOS app, using a subclass of `PFSignUpViewController` to create news users, one at a time.

It works fine but here is my problem: sometime I want to create multiple users in one go. Say around 50 users in one time.
Obviously I do not want to type them in one by one; I have them ready in a list:

```
email-01, username-01
email-02, username-02
email-03, username-03
.. etc ..
```

How can I do that? Is it possible within the iOS app, by some function call?
Or do I need to use some external tool?

Michel

Comment: I think you can recursively call the `[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){ }` method. Store your 50 users in an array of dictionaries(or JSON), then retrieve them one by one after successfully sign up one user.

Comment: That sounds good, but where does signUpInBackgroundWithBlock come from? I have to check that.

Comment: Please check the Parse documentation: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#signing-up

Comment: Great. I am using Swift not Objectiv C as in the example. But I just tried with one user creation and that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a sample project for you, you can sign them up by just using a `for` loop.

And of course, you can set up all your users in a JSON file, then use `JSONSerialization` to get the JSON contents.

Here is the sample project:

```
let userArray = [
    ["username":"user1","email":"abc@a.com","password":"1234"],
    ["username":"user2","email":"abc@b.com","password":"1234"],
    ["username":"user3","email":"abc@c.com","password":"1234"],
    ["username":"user4","email":"abc@d.com","password":"1234"],
    ["username":"user5","email":"abc@e.com","password":"1234"]
]

@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var index = 0
    for _ in userArray {
        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = userArray[index]["username"]
        user.password = userArray[index]["password"]
        user.email    = userArray[index]["email"]
        user.signUpInBackground()

        index += 1
    }
}
```

and there you go, all five users are signed up.
[image]

Comment: Yes, it works now. I did it making a recursive call in the completion handler (your first idea), but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: @Michel I'm glad it worked for you. But I do think using a `for` loop is very straight forward and simpler :) Anyway, since it works now, both are fine.